# Do I need riak to run hallway (Singly)?

Tags: riak

In the taskman section of the hallway config there is a section about riak. I wonder if riak is necesary to run the API.

```
"taskman": {
    "numWorkers": 4,
    "pagingTiming": 2000,
    "defaultScanTime": 5000,
    "attempts": 8,
    "heartbeat": 10000,
    "store": {
      "type": "riak",
      "servers": ["localhost:8098"]
    },
    "redis": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 6379
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the commit that added that on github:

https://github.com/Singly/hallway/commit/5eb59ae0185373c89f401cf5024f35cb2719f033

It would appear that as of 17 days ago that yes, Riak is the *default* K/V store for task metadata in the config.

Poking around a bit more finds that this is user configurable and be changed to 'fs' or 'mem':

https://github.com/Singly/hallway/pull/758#issuecomment-12725475